# W2UI multi keyword search

Tags: jquery, w2ui, grid-search

W2UI GRID

I want to have grid search like in datatables .net

It uses `'AND'` condition for search text separated by space.

My requirement is not to use that advance search which is already there next to search box because it is specific column based.

```
"records": [
{ "recid": 1, "fname": "John", "lname": "Doe", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
{ "recid": 2, "fname": "John", "lname": "Motzart", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
{ "recid": 3, "fname": "John", "lname": "Franson", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
{ "recid": 4, "fname": "Susan", "lname": "Franson", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
{ "recid": 5, "fname": "Kelly", "lname": "Franson", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
{ "recid": 6, "fname": "Francis", "lname": "Franson", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
{ "recid": 7, "fname": "Mark", "lname": "Welldo", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
{ "recid": 8, "fname": "Thomas", "lname": "Bahh", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
{ "recid": 9, "fname": "Sergei", "lname": "Rachmaninov", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" }
]
```

Now in `w2ui` grid search box I am searching "John"
then it should display `1,2,3 records`

Then I am searching "john fran" 
then it should only display `3rd record.`

how to achieve this?

**I have tried splitting string of search box by space and made changes in w2ui.js
but It always searches for the last word in search string,**

please help , thanks :) :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by adding a new value of "fullname" to your records.

```
records: [
{ "recid": 1, "fname": "John", "lname": "Doe", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012", "fullname": "John Doe" },
{ "recid": 2, "fname": "John", "lname": "Motzart", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012", "fullname": "John Motzart" },
{ "recid": 3, "fname": "John", "lname": "Franson", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012", "fullname": "John Franson" },
{ "recid": 4, "fname": "Susan", "lname": "Franson", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012", "fullname": "Susan Franson" },
{ "recid": 5, "fname": "Kelly", "lname": "Franson", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012", "fullname": "Kelly Franson" },
{ "recid": 6, "fname": "Francis", "lname": "Franson", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012", "fullname": "Francis Franson" },
{ "recid": 7, "fname": "Mark", "lname": "Welldo", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012", "fullname": "Mark Welldo" },
{ "recid": 8, "fname": "Thomas", "lname": "Bahh", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012", "fullname": "Thomas Bahh" },
{ "recid": 9, "fname": "Sergei", "lname": "Rachmaninov", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012", "fullname": "Sergei Rachmaninov" }
```

and then you can add this properties to your grid to search data based on the "fullname" value.

```
searches: [
            { field: 'fullname', caption: 'Name', operator: 'begins', type: 'text' }
        ]
```